# In a figurebox, how can we display captions to the right of images in order to save space?

Tags: graphics, floats

I currently have a figure that appears as

```
\begin{figure}
\figuresize{.6}
\figurebox{25pc}{25pc}{}[figure1]
\caption{LONG Caption here}
\label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}
```

but the caption is long and I'd like to save space by moving it to the right of the figure, so that the figure is to the left, with the caption to the right. Is it possible with the above set-up? Thanks

Comment: Please  post a minimal, yet complete, code illustrating your problem.

Comment: I cannot find \figurebox in any package I have loaded.  The closest is \subcaptionbox from the subcaption package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[capbesideposition=right, facing=yes,capbesidesep=qquad]{floatrow}%can use quad also

\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \fcapside[\FBwidth]
        {\caption{A nice figure with a very very very very long long caption}\label{key}} 
        {\rule{4cm}{4cm}} %Replace with image
    \end{figure}


\begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}{.75\textwidth}
        \rule{8cm}{4cm} %Replace with image
    \end{minipage}  
    \begin{minipage}[]{.15\textwidth}
        \rotcaption{A nice figure.}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```